# Sort log file using join

Tags: bash, shell, join, awk

I have a file that contains entries sorted by timestamp, but which contains multiple instances of the same timestamp, each with a seperate topic. I would like to concatenate all entries with the same timestamp onto one line. Timestamp is column 1

Input file might read

```
Time,Tag,Value  
1,ABC,3  
2,ABC,2.7  
2,DEF,3.4  
3,ABC,2.8  
3,DEF,3.6  
3,GHI,2.99  
3,JKL,3.01  
4,ABC,3.42  
4,DEF,3.62  
4,JKL,3.82
```

And desired output would be like (option 1);

```
Time,Tag,Value  
1,ABC,3  
2,ABC,2.7,DEF,3.4  
3,ABC,2.8,DEF,3.6,GHI,2.99,JKL,3.01  
4,ABC,3.42,DEF,3.62,JKL,3.82
```

And even better would be (option 2);

```
1,ABC,3  
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4  
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01  
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

I presume that I can get to option 1 by writing a script using a loop. Which would firstly require me to get the unique list of all values of 'Tag', to determine how many iterations I need to loop through.

But I am also assuming that;

1) Even in bash this could be expensive for long files and;
2) There may well be some more elegant way of doing this.

Newb question. All assistance appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Better write a full fledged high level program or a shell script, if you need maintenance for the same, because the one-liners would be hard to debug and understand after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in chronological order, you could use this awk solution:

*parse.awk*

```
# Use comma as input and output field separators
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

# Print header and skip to next line
NR == 1 { print; next }

# If previous timestamp is the same as current append tag and value
pt == $1 {
  tag = tag "|" $2
  val = val "|" $3
}

# If not the first data line and timestamps are not equal then print
NR != 2 && pt != $1 { print pt, tag, val }

# Save previous timestamp and reset accumulator variables    
pt != $1 {
  pt  = $1
  tag = $2
  val = $3
}

END { print pt, tag, val }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
<infile awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print;next} pt==$1 {tag=tag"|"$2;val=val"|"$3} NR!=2&&pt!=$1 {print pt,tag,val} pt!=$1 {pt=$1;tag=$2;val=$3} END {print pt,tag,val}'
```

Comment: Thanks - that works v well and I can see well enough what's going on to have been able to add support for a fourth column. I think I can use this one as the basis for further work. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Pascoe, I'm glad it helped you. On stackoverflow the way to say thanks is by upvoting useful answers and accepting the most useful answer.

Comment: will do. To be honest ALL were useful in general terms, but yours I could most easily understand (and was therefore able to tweak later). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

this would work:

```
awk -F, '{if($1 in a){ split(a[$1],t,","); a[$1]=t[1]"|"$2","t[2]"|"$3
}else a[$1]=$2","$3;}END{asort(a);for(x in a)print x","a[x]}' file|sort -n
```

with your example:

```
kent$  awk -F, '{if($1 in a){split(a[$1],t,","); a[$1]=t[1]"|"$2","t[2]"|"$3
}else a[$1]=$2","$3;}END{asort(a);for(x in a)print x","a[x]}' file|sort -n                                                                                                  
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Comment: Thanks - that's 99% there. Yields the desired result and then adds a line 5 which is as follows;  5,Tag,Value

Comment: what is the missing 1% part? you mean the header/title line?

Comment: In addition I was giving a simplified version as my real example has more columns. But now I know the syntax I'm happy to have a crack at solving for a file with 6 data columns. Plus to get the unique value for the 'tag' I an concatenating two columns. But I also appreciate that newbs asking to be spoonfed entire answers isn't the desired behaviour here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

***NEW ANSWER:***

I realize that my previous answer may be difficult to read and understand - especially for beginners. It does however make good use of gawk's array sorting functionality, which would be highly beneficial in dealing with unique values of the 'tags' you talk about in your question. However, after reading some of the comments, I believe I may have mis-understood your question - perhaps only slightly. Here's a method that doesn't care about the uniqueness of the 'tags' and their values. It just joins them all up. It should also be very readable and scalable too. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of script.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

NR==1 {
    print
    next
}

{
    tag[$1]=(tag[$1] ? tag[$1] "|" : "") $2
    val[$1]=(val[$1] ? val[$1] "|" : "") $3
}

END {
    for (i in tag) {
        print i, tag[i], val[i] | "sort -n"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { print; next } { tag[$1]=(tag[$1] ? tag[$1] "|" : "") $2; val[$1]=(val[$1] ? val[$1] "|" : "") $3 } END { for (i in tag) print i, tag[i], val[i] | "sort -n" }' OFS=, file
```

---

***PREVIOUS ANSWER:***

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

NR==1 {
    print
    next
}

{
    a[$1][$2]=$3
}

END {

    for (i in a) {
        b[x++] = i
    }

    n = asort(b)

    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {

        m = asorti(a[b[j]],c)

        for (k=1;k<=m;k++) {

            s = (s ? s "|" : "") c[k]
            r = (r ? r "|" : "") a[b[j]][c[k]]
        }

        print b[j], s, r
        s = r = ""
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { print; next } { a[$1][$2]=$3 } END { for (i in a) b[x++] = i; n = asort(b); for (j=1;j<=n;j++) { m = asorti(a[b[j]],c); for (k=1;k<=m;k++) { s = (s ? s "|" : "") c[k]; r = (r ? r "|" : "") a[b[j]][c[k]] } print b[j], s, r; s = r = "" } }' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash` is probably the wrong tool for this. Try Python:

```
import fileinput
import sys

oldTime = None
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.strip()
    pos = line.find(',')
    time = line[0:pos]
    if oldTime == time:
        sys.stdout.write(',')
        sys.stdout.write(line[pos+1:])
    else:
        if oldTime is not None:
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.write(line)

    oldTime = time

sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an operation that you would like to repeat often, I would opt for a utility script written in a more *'complete'* scripting language. You can then call the script within your own bash script or use it in the command line as and when needed.

Here's a Python example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# --- merge_groups.py ----
import fileinput, operator, itertools
lines = (line.strip() for line in fileinput.input())
data = (line.split(",") for line in lines if line)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0)):
  _, label, value =  zip(*group)
  print "%s,%s,%s" % (key, "|".join(label), "|".join(value))
```

Note that the script assumes that the entries with the same timestamp are already grouped together.

You can use the script to process existing data files or pipe data directly to it, e.g:

```
[me@home]$ ./merge_groups.py data.txt  # parse existing data file
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82

[me@home]$ cat data.txt | ./merge_groups.py  # post-process command output
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Comment: Hmmm - got an odd error message
$ /usr/local/bin/testpy.py jt.csv
Time,Tag,Value
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/testpy.py", line 7, in <module>
_, label, value =  zip(*group)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Sorry - this mini-Markdown is killing me.

Comment: Does you input CSV file contain lines that has more than or less than 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

@AaronDigulla and @Kent have some good solutions, but if you have/would like to go with bash, here's one:

```
for ts in `cat inputfile | cut --delimiter="," --fields=1 | uniq`
do
  p1="";
  p2="";
  for line in `grep "^${ts}," inputfile | cut --delimiter="," --fields=2-`
  do
    f1=`echo ${line} | cut --delimiter="," --fields=1`;
    f2=`echo ${line} | cut --delimiter="," --fields=2`;
    p1=${p1}"|"$f1;
    p2=${p2}"|"$f2;
  done
  echo ${ts}","${p1#?}","${p2#?};
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want one more awk solution!

```
function read() {
  split($0, buf, ",")
}

function write() {
  for (i = 1; i < length(buf); i++) {
    printf "%s,", buf[i]
  }
  print buf[length(buf)]
}

BEGIN {
  FS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
  print
  next
}

NR == 2 {
  read()
  next
}

{
  if ($1 != time) { # new time                                                                                                                                                                   
    time = $1
    write()
    read()
  } else { # repeated time                                                                                                                                                                       
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
      buf[i] = buf[i] "|" $i
    }
  }
}

END {
  write()
}
```

I'm not that good with awk, so I had to emphasize readability!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you did say *"all assistance",* so would that include a Ruby solution?

```
require 'csv'

puts(CSV.read('f.csv').group_by(&:first).map do |k, v|
  t = v.transpose
  [k, t[1].join('|'), t[2].join('|')].join(',')
end.drop(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl is unrepresented.

```
use strict;
my $skip_header = <>;
my %d;
while(<>) {
    s/\s+$//;
    my ($no, $k, $v )  = split ",";
    push @{$d{int($no)}}, [ $k,  $v ];
}
END {
    foreach my $no (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %d  )  {
        print $no, ",";
        print join("|", map { $_->[0] } @{$d{$no}});
        print ",";
        print join("|", map { $_->[1] } @{$d{$no}});
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first option, you could try:

```
awk -F, 'p x!=$1{if(p x)print s; p=s=$1} {sub($1,x); s=s $0} END{print s}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

first one:

```
> awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2","$3}END{for(i in a)print i","substr(a[i],2)}' temp | sort
1,ABC,3
2,ABC,2.7,DEF,3.4
3,ABC,2.8,DEF,3.6,GHI,2.99,JKL,3.01
4,ABC,3.42,DEF,3.62,JKL,3.82
```

second one:

```
> awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]"|"$2;b[$1]=b[$1]"|"$3}END{for(i in a)print i","substr(a[i],2)","substr(b[i],2)}' temp | sort
1,ABC,3
2,ABC|DEF,2.7|3.4
3,ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL,2.8|3.6|2.99|3.01
4,ABC|DEF|JKL,3.42|3.62|3.82
```

Answer (score 0):

### Shorter: `sed` way

```
sed -ne ':a;$!N;/^\([0-9]\+\),.*\n\1,/s/\n[0-9]*//;ta;P;D'
Time,Tag,Value
1,ABC,3
2,ABC,2.7,DEF,3.4
3,ABC,2.8,DEF,3.6,GHI,2.99,JKL,3.01
4,ABC,3.42,DEF,3.62,JKL,3.82
```